# Header and footer top and bottom margin

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I have a s cript that generates a docx file, everything is ok with the exception that the header and footer are not align to top and bottom.

I have

```
        mydoc = docx.Document()
        section_g = mydoc.sections
        section_h = mydoc.sections[0]
        header = section_h.header
        header_para = header.paragraphs[0]
        footer = section_h.footer
        footer_para = footer.paragraphs[0]


        for section in section_g:
            section.top_margin = Cm(0)
            section.bottom_margin = Cm(0)
            section.left_margin = Cm(0)
            section.right_margin = Cm(0)
```

This works great for the rest of the document but the header and footer top and left margin is not 0.

What am i missing? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "header and footer are not align"? You'll need to be more specific before we can help you. Perhaps include a screen-grab and say what you expect/want and what you're seeing now.

Comment: header is not on top of the page it has a margin of something like 5cm and bottom the same is has a margin of about 5cm from the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the API documentation for `Section.header_distance` and `.footer_distance` here: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/section.html#docx.section.Section.header_distance

I think this is the setting you're after. Basically it determines the space between the top or bottom of the page and the header or footer respectively. By adjusting these values in conjunction with the top and bottom margin values you can adjust where the header and footer start and where the "body" text begins and ends vertically.